# "if" doesn't work in React's componentWillMount()

Tags: javascript, if-statement, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have created a component "App", which has a function `componentWillMount` defined (it should redirect react router when condition is false).

```
componentWillMount() {
    const isLoggedIn = session.getLogin()
    console.log( 'isLoggedIn is', isLoggedIn )
    if ( !isLoggedIn ) {
        console.log( 'now its false!' )
    } else {
        console.log( 'else' )
    }
    return false
}
```

But the console outputs the following:

```
isLoggedIn is false
else
```

Am I doing something wrong? I was thinking that having `isLoggedIn` set to false, the console should say "now its false!", but **it doesn't**.

Just to note - session.getLogin() does `return sessionstorage.getItem('sessionLoggedIn')`

Thank you for anwsers.

Comment: Are you sure `sessionstorage.getItem('sessionLoggedIn')` returns a boolean and not a string?

Comment: Why didn't I think of that! You're right, it's all working. Sorry for stupid question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sessionStorage saves all its entries as Strings, thus the value you are getting out of there is actually `'false'`. So you need to check if the string returned is only `'true'`:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const isLoggedIn = session.getLogin() === 'true'
    console.log( 'isLoggedIn is', isLoggedIn )
    if ( !isLoggedIn ) {
        console.log( 'now its false!' )
    } else {
        console.log( 'else' )
    }
    return false
}
```

Apart from that, if this is actually a login functionality, it's very insecure.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't realise it's a string. It's not supposed to be secure though, It's just an internal check.

Answer (score 1):

sessionStorage saves your data only on the browser tab you opening

```
componentWillMount() {
    return auth.isAuthenticated();
}
```

meanwhile auth is an auth helper

```
const auth = {
  isAuthenticated() {
    if (typeof window === "undefined")
      return false

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('jwt'))
      return sessionStorage.getItem('jwt')
    else
      return false
  },
  authenticate(jwt, cb) {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined")
    sessionStorage.setItem('jwt', jwt)
    cb();
  },
  signout(cb) {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined"){
      sessionStorage.clear();
    }

    cb()
    signout().then((data) => {
      sessionStorage.clear();
      document.cookie = "t=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;"
    })
  }
}
```